# Possibility to auto refresh launch in reportportal.io

Tags: automated-tests, reporting, test-reporting, reportportal

is there any way to auto refresh my launch screen on reportportal.io?

Currently, in order to actually see my results in real time I have to manually click refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Not now. We avoid it to keep server safe, limiting number of requests.

but
we started already migration of UI on ReactJS.
and with it, we will add WebSocket connections.
This will look like push-updates.

will be available with 4.1 or so.

please check our roadmap here
https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/wiki/Roadmap-4.0